# How make countdown in flutter after done back to login page?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello flutter's developers after login to second page but after 30sec for example I want to back page or logout to first page. How I can make it

Comment: Please, add the code so that the issue is possible to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we have only 2 pages. One is the `FirstPage` the other is the `SecondPage`.

```dart
Future<void> counter() async{
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30)).then(
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
  );
}
```

Calling the above code in the `initState` function of `SecondPage` will help you get back to the `FirstPage`.

For example:

```dart
initState(){
  super.initState();
  // Please note that I am not using await over here because `initState` cannot 
  // be an asynchronous function.
  counter();
}
```

Comment: Also, use `pushReplacement` for replace second screen. If you push to a first screen without replace it, a user can go back to second screen.

Comment: Thank you. I will make the necessary edits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a Timer:

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage())),
          child: Text('LOGIN'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  final int initialCountDown;
  Timer _timer;
  int _counter;
  double get progress => _counter / initialCountDown;

  _SecondPageState([this.initialCountDown = 10]);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _counter = initialCountDown;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      (_) {
        setState(() => _counter--);
        if (_counter == 0) {
          // Call your signout
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('You will soon be logged out.'),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            CircularProgressIndicator(value: progress),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```